# IIS hosted wcf service cannot load BehaviorExtension

Tags: wcf, iis, behavior

**Hello I have a big problem with adding my customservicebehavior to a IIs hosted service.
this is what I posted in my web.config:

```
</behavior>
<behavior name="BehaviorExtension">
<ServiceHostBehavior />
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<extensions>
<behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="ServiceHostBehavior" type="CustomBehavior.ServiceHostBehavior, CustomBehavior,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
</behaviorExtensions>
</extensions>
```

but everytime I want to connect to my service via my browser i get this errormessage:
The type 'CustomBehavior.ServiceHostBehavior, CustomBehavior,  Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' registered for extension 'ServiceHostBehavior' could not be loaded.**

I made a new project in which I get the name from the behavior-assembly. This works fine...

It also works if I reference this assembly in an app.config file in another project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok fixed it by registering my CustomBehavior assembly in the GAC. Now it works

Comment: For future reference, you can use a utility called Fuslogvw to find out exactly why a .NET assembly cannot be loaded. In this case it sounds like it was just looking on the wrong file path for the assembly.